# In Yahoo Messenger, when I appear online to only a few selected contacts (from the Stealth Settings menu), how can I set a status for them to see?

Tags: contacts, yahoo-messenger

In Yahoo Messenger, when I'm signed on as invisible, and I right-click a contact and in the Stealth Settings I set "Appear online to ", can I set a status for that contact to see? And the rest see me as invisible?

Comment: Are you asking to have this apply all the time so you don't have to keep doing it every time you sign back in?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, that is the purpose of stealth mode. You can appear online to certain contacts that you want and be invisible to the rest of the world. Just right click on any contact and in Stealth Settings, choose Appear Online.

Comment: Yes, but when I appear online, can I also set a status to them, different than "Available"? That's what I want to do, set a status *only* to the people that see me online, and to the rest to remain invisible.

Comment: The way to do that would be to sign in as invisible and then selectively appear online to only those you want. Hope this helps!!